# Get the value for each control from a list of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm struggling to get the input value from a control in JavaScript, and I think it may have something to do with the collection of controls I'm looping through.

My page consists of many input controls with decimals in them. I'm only interested in controls starting with the name 'txtinput', and I need to tally up the values in each one. However, when I do this with the code below, all I seem to be getting out is a JSON looking string for each element.

```
 function TallyPoints() {

    var eles = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var total = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name.indexOf('txtpoints') == 0) {
            total += document.getElementsByName(inputs[i].name)[0].value;
        }
    }

    alert('Total: ' + total.toString());

};
```

What I end up with is a value that looks like this:

```
Total: 0{"enabled":false,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"333.33","valueAsString":"333.33","minValue":-70368744177664,"maxValue":70368744177664,"lastSetTextBoxValue":"333.33"}{"enabled":false,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"5.66","valueAsString":"5.66","minValue":-70368744177664,"maxValue":70368744177664,"lastSetTextBoxValue":"5.66"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `inputs[i].value` instead of looking it up by name again?

Comment: You just want a count for all inputs 'txtpoints'? Like if you have 3 'txtinputs' you have to output: "Total: 3" ?

Comment: You should also use `parseFloat()` before adding. The value is a string, so `+` does concatenation, not arithmetic.

Comment: @Barmar inputs[i].value has the same result. If I use parseFloat, I get a NaN value. I'm using: total += parseFloat(inputs[i].value);

Comment: @MatheusLima I want to tally up the decimal values in each textbox.

Comment: If you're getting `NaN`, it means the input doesn't contain a number. You apparently have an input that contains a JSON string for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) so your addition works properly ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/ALmKG/)):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^=txtpoints]");
var total = [].reduce.call(inputs, function (p, c) {
    return p + (parseFloat(c.value) || 0);
}, 0);
```

<sub>See also  [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseint), [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), and `Array.prototype.reduce()`</sub>

Comment: I wonder why this works and my answer doesn't. This just uses a different way to skip over the non-numeric inputs. But either way, if they're all non-numeric, you should be getting a zero total.

Comment: Something here changed and no longer works at all. The original also had a flaw though... it was double-counting for some reason it seems.

Comment: @canon That's strange. I saw the change you made to the selector, and thought it was that. So I put an alert(inputs.length.toString()); and it returned me double the inputs I'm looking for. Then I figured it must have been a mistake and wasn't filtering the controls properly. I wonder what's going on?

Comment: Here's what changed: I updated my selector to use `input[name^=txtpoints]` rather than `input:not([name*=txtpoints])`. Your code `inputs[i].name.indexOf('txtpoints') == 0` says, _"find inputs whose name begins with `txtpoints`."_ I initially misread that as _"doesn't contain"_. This version is correct and it works in the linked fiddle. This may suggest that your own code contains a typo.

Comment: @drminnaar create a mock-up on http://jsfiddle.net/ which reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function TallyPoints() {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var total = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name.indexOf('txtpoints') == 0) {
            var val = parseFloat(inputs[i].value);
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                total += val;
            }
        }
    }

    alert('Total: ' + total);

};
```

`parseFloat` is needed to convert the input from a string to a number, so that `+` will do addition rather than concatenation. There's no need to use `getElementsByName`, since you already have the element in `inputs[i]`. There's no need to use `total.toString()`; concatenating a number to a string converts it automatically.

The `if (!isNan(val))` test skips over the inputs that don't contain numbers.

You could also use `document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=txtpoints]')` to find the relevant `input` elements in one step.

Comment: Now I get 0, which tells me everything is NaN. How can we simplify this to isolate the problem?

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger. Set a breakpoint in the loop and look at `inputs[i].value`.